# Using two querySelector in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use js in a way that when you hover the mouse over text links, the background image changes with each link.
I've been able to initiate the Event Listener to the link texts but am unable to direct the output to the background image div (style elemet)

Here is my html code

```
<div id="livestream">  
      </div>
      <div id="wedding">  
      </div>
      <div id="documentary">  
      </div>

      <div class="container text-box">
          <a href="#">Livestreaming</a> 
          <a href="#">Weddings</a>
          <a href="#">Documentaries</a>
      </div>
```

My css, which im stuck too;

```
.landing #documentary{
    background-image: url("/img/pic-01.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1;
}

.landing #livestream, #wedding, #documentary{
    display: none;
}

.text-box a:nth-child(1):hover{
    color: #e08416;
    transition: 0.4s ease;}
}
```

And here is my js code

```
document.querySelector('.text-box a:nth-child(1)').addEventListener('mouseenter', entering);
document.querySelector('.text-box a:nth-child(1)').addEventListener('mouseleave', leaving);

function entering(ev){
    ev.currentTarget.style.display = "block";
    console.log('mouseenter  a');
}

function leaving(ev){
    ev.currentTarget.style.display = "none";
    console.log('mouseleave a');
}
```

I got stuck here!

Comment: There's no reason to scope ID selectors, since there will (should) only ever be _one per page_. Change `.landing #documentary` to `#documentary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `querySelector` in the `entering` or `leaving` method to capture the element you need. Or in this case, it's simpler to call the `parentElement` of the item.

```js
function entering(ev){
    ev.currentTarget.parentElement.style.display = "block";
    console.log('mouseenter  a');
}

function leaving(ev){
    ev.currentTarget.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    console.log('mouseleave a');
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, I works but it only affects the ```parentElement```
On the other hand, I want to affect a different element in my case is ```div #livestream ``` and the rest. How to I go about this

Comment: In that case, you can use a querySelector to get the node and apply the styles.
`querySelector('#livestream').style.display = "......"`